# Where to get balance sheet and income statement info for many companies?

Tags: balance-sheet

Is there a way to get raw data of balance sheets and income statements for many companies at once?
What I would like to do it scan many tickers at once to see which have low  p/e and current/cash ratios etc so I'd would like to put current assets, current liabilites etc in a spreadsheet and make some formulas so I can quickly scan which companies are better values than others.

If I go to finance.google.com I have to put in each ticker one by one to get the data and then copy and paste it. There has to be a better way.

Anyone know where I can get such data?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the financial data sources require a (hefty) subscription, but for a simple screener two simple (and free) options to look at are [just using a Google Spreadsheet with the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en), or if you need something more formal, [Quandl provides a free API](https://www.quandl.com/tools/api) (you pay for premium data sets).